# Why is my the designated initializer of UIViewController never called?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I created a new Xcode project with a view-based app template. In the .m of the view controller I overwrote this:

```
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization

        NSLog(@"initWithNibName...");
    }
    return self;
}


- (id)init {
    NSLog(@"initWithNibName...");
    return [super init];
}
```

However, I never get that NSLog. That's also my experience from other projects. This method is never called. Not even -init from NSObject.

The View Controller is created inside the XIB file. How's that possible, that the Nib Loading System instantiates this class without any kind of initialization?

Why? And what's the alternative instead of -loadView and -viewDidLoad?

Another great reason to stay far away from XIB files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the iOS [Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> In iPhone OS, any object that conforms to the NSCoding protocol is initialized using the `initWithCoder:` method. This includes all subclasses of `UIView` and `UIViewController` whether they are part of the default Interface Builder library or custom classes you define.

Think of it this way: the designated initializer is called when your view controller is first created in Interface Builder. Then, when you save the nib file, the view controller instance is stored in the file. Later, when the nib is loaded, the instance is recreated from the nib.

Since it's being recreated rather than created for the first time, a different initialization method is used. This method (`-initWithCoder:`) restores the object's state using values from the nib file, which can include settings for properties beyond those that were set by the designated initializer. This mechanism relies on the `NSCoding` protocol, which allows it to work generically for many different classes.

Comment: It should be noted that initWithNibName:bundle: will get called if you're using a nib and instantiating the view controller by calling initWithNibName:bundle: directly. It's just that usually these days you're using storyboards, in which case it will call initWithCoder: instead. Before storyboards I'm guessing the default Xcode project view-based app template didn't call initWithNibName:bundle: to instantiate the initial view controller.

Comment: @LironYahdav If you reread the question, you'll note that it states that the view controller is *in* the nib file, so there's no way that `initWithNibName:bundle:` can be called when the nib is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use - awakeFromNib for this. 
The init is only called if you do so in code.

Comment: thanks for that hint! but anyways, how can it be that the Nib Loader creates instances of this class without doing any init?

Comment: All objects that are loaded from a NIB (or another NSCoding archive) are initialized with `-initWithCoder:`.

Comment: makes sense, but why is -init never called? it's the designated initializer of NSObject...

Comment: -awakeFromNib is not an initializer, it belongs to the view controller life cycle and it can be called more than once (specially when dealing with memory warnings; the view controller might release the views and reconstruct them later). So be careful what you put here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your MainWindow's delegate as your appDelegate..?
Implement `UIApplicationDelegate` in your AppDelegate and in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` Methode,try `initWithNibName`.
That will do the trick.